# Voting to close new users' questions without comment

Tags: discussion

This question, [How to compile the bootloader mega 2560 to 57600 speed?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34127/how-to-compile-the-bootloader-mega-2560-to-57600-speed), by a new user, has four close votes, but no comments.

Yes, it is a terrible question, *as it stands*, and yes, if it was from a seasoned user, then it could/should be voted to close without  comment, as they should know better.

However, as this is a new user, who probably doesn't understand how SE works, a little prompt in a comment, won't hurt. Yes, they should have read the "tour", but when you are looking for an answer, and you are new to SE, then having to wade through the tour, is the last thing on your mind.

I've left a comment, and if no update appears after a few days then yes, it should be closed, as the user has probably disappeared, found their own solution, or no longer cares.

The point I'm trying to make is that, if you are reviewing, and see a bad question, check to see how long the user has been on the site and bearing in mind that we were all "dumb" new users once, just give them a nod in the right direction...

Comment: I would encourage all users to leave a comment if the post needs some work - we all need to be educated about how SE works. I would go further ans say that comments should even comment on experienced users posts if they are not up to scratch. The reason: new users read these posts, so while you might not be educating the OP you will educate all those reading it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Arduino SE is a site for newbies (generally speaking) so I think we have to be reasonably tolerant of questions that look a bit vague. If it was Astrophysics Stack Exchange you might expect people to know more about the subject material.

Answer (score 0):

[I want to use this post, [How to merge 2 batteries socketof 6v each](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43104/how-to-merge-2-batteries-socketof-6v-each), as a reference.]

I think guys that doesn't know the Ohm's law and doesn't know how to program are beyond redemption. And they want help building an intergalactic laser shooting robot by 2:00 PM, fast!

No amount of help will do any good for them. They are people that don't make any effort learning; they come here to have someone solve their needs.

This kind of posts degrade this site quality. They are not good for the OP and for the rest, it is just junk, pollution.

I vote for a quicker and stricter repeal of junk posts.

Comment: Some question is clearly under par, but who is SE for? Professionals only witch complicated questions and minimum of 25 years in the business or someone that don't have the skills or experience, but would like to get a answer to something basic? The "Be nice" policy talks about be patience, help and guide. I have seen some ironic, rude and not that inviting/welcoming comments and how is this hurting the SE Arduino's reputation?

Comment: Programming is hard; so is electronic. You need years of study to reach just entry-level skills. You can't replace years of study with random tips & advices from Internet. People that think so are *dilettantes*, persons who takes up an art, activity, or subject merely for amusement, especially in a desultory or superficial way.